# Problem calculating commutator with Casimir

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, lie-algebra, commutator

I am trying to verify that the Casimir of the Lie group $SO(3)$ is actually $N^2=N_iN_i$, but I have problems, with indices surely, and I was wondering if someone could help me figuring out how to properly verify these commutation relation. Here is what I come up with:

$$
\left[N^2,N_j\right]
{=N^2N_j-N_jN^2\nonumber\\
=(N_iN_i)N_j-N_j(N_iN_i)\nonumber\\
=N_iN_jN_i+N_i[N_i,N_j]-N_jN_iN_i\nonumber\\
=N_jN_iN_i+[N_i,N_j]N_i+N_ii\epsilon^{ijk}N_k-N_jN_iN_i\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i+N_ii\epsilon^{ijk}N_k\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_iN_k(2+[N_k,N_i])\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_iN_k(2+i\epsilon^{kij}N_j)\nonumber}
$$

I don't see how this is supposed to give $0$.

Comment: Try checking your index structure -- halfway you switch from having good indices to having three copies of some indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same through line 5. Line 6 starts being different:
$$
\left[N^2,N_j\right]
{=N^2N_j-N_jN^2\nonumber\\
=(N_iN_i)N_j-N_j(N_iN_i)\nonumber\\
=N_iN_jN_i+N_i[N_i,N_j]-N_jN_iN_i\nonumber\\
=N_jN_iN_i+[N_i,N_j]N_i+N_ii\epsilon^{ijk}N_k-N_jN_iN_i\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i+N_ii\epsilon^{ijk}N_k\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i+i\epsilon^{ijk}N_iN_k\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i-i\epsilon^{kji}N_iN_k\nonumber\\
=i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i-i\epsilon^{ijk}N_kN_i\nonumber \quad relabeled \quad indices\\ 
=0}
$$

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot! I did not think about this particular relabeling trick. Must add it to my useful tools! Thanks again!